# Conditional Formula SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, conditional-formatting

I have the following list
[List for Users to select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aMUf.png) based on their choices, there should be a calculated formula between the Current Month versus the monthly period they indicated that the project would start to return a Tracking Status of "On Track", "Delayed" or "N/A".  Could anyone please help me with the formula?
[Tracking Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A88sV.png)

In Excel this formula would work as: '=IF(AND(JUSTIFICATION="Not Started",MONTHLY PERIOD-5<CURRENT MONTH),"Delayed",IF(AND(CLEAR="Not Started",MONTHLY PERIOD-4<CURRENT MONTH),"Delayed",IF(AND(CONTRACT="Not Started",MONTHLY PERIOD-3<CURRENT MONTH),"Delayed",IF(AND(PO="Not Started",MONTHLY PERIOD-2<CURRENT MONTH),"Delayed",IF(AND(BILLING="Not Started",MONTHLY PERIOD-1<CURRENT MONTH),"Delayed","On Track")))))

or

[Excel formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqb0D.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1.Create the below columns in the list

- Period: Number
- Justification: Choices
- Clear: Choices
- Contract: Choices
- PO: Choices
- Billing: Choices
- First period with Spead: Number
- Overall Execations Status: Calculated (calculation based on other columns)

[image]

2.Use the Formula:

```
=IF(AND([Justification]="Not Started",[First period with Spead]-5<[Period]),"Deplayed",IF(AND([Clear]="Not Started",[First period with Spead]-4<[Period]),"Deplayed",IF(AND([Contract]="Not Started",[First period with Spead]-3<[Period]),"Deplayed",IF(AND([PO]="Not Started",[First period with Spead]-2<[Period]),"Deplayed",IF(AND([Billing]="Not Started",[First period with Spead]-1<[Period]),"Deplayed","On Track")))))
```

[image]

3.Click on **All Items** >> **Edit current view**

[image]

4.On the Edit View page, scroll to "**Group By**" section

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi EchoDu_MSFT,  I am so grateful for your review, work, and prompt detailed response.  Ten thousand thank you!!  It worked like a charm! Thank you for your knowledge, skills and wiliness for helping others!  I love SharePoint and am trying to plug an Excel report into SharePoint, and will probably be posting help here, I hope you will be able to help me again.  Many thanks and please be safe!

Comment: Hi SP-new. I am happy to be able to help you solve the problem. I also wish you good health and all the best.